# UIImage return nil only in a UIImageView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm new in iOS programming, and I have a strange problem...

I created a tableview, add cells with "subtitle" style. In my code, I can set the image, all works fine. the code `(g, gf and picturesArray are strings array)` :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString * cellIdentifier = @"fCellID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    NSString *feed = [self.g objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *feed1 = [self.gf objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *feed2 = [self.picturesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.textLabel setText:feed];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:feed1];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:feed2];
    return cell;
}
```

Next, I want to go to a new view when I click on a cell. Here the code :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    GUDdfViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GUdfView"];

    detail.titleString = [self.gf objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detail.descriptionString = [self.gfs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detail.contentString = [self.gfc objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detail.imageNameString = [self.picturesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
}
```

OK. All works; in my new view, title and subtitle are present with good content.
BUT ! the image is not displayed... Here the line where I set the image in "GUDdfViewController" :

```
[self.pictureLogoOutlet setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.imageNameString]];
```

When I use `NSLog`, it says me that my object `(pictureLogoOutlet.image)` is `null`. I also tried this :

```
[self.pictureLogoOutlet setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"baguette.png"]];
```

but the problem is the same...

Do you know why I have this problem ? I really don't understand.

Comment: Have you added the image file to the project's target?

Comment: Continue to use logging to investigate: is `self.pictureLogoOutlet` itself nil? I'm betting it is.

Comment: You're on the right track.  You just need to understand why the outlet isn't initialized.  Naturally if it's nil, setting an image property on nil will do nothing.  Is it connected in IB?  Are you calling setImage: after viewDidLoad has completed?  (It appears that way from your posted code.  Put a breakpoint in GUDdfVc viewDidLoad and one on the setImage and see which breakpoint is triggered first

Answer (score 0):

pictureLogoOutlet in nil because your GUDdfViewController has not yet initialized its IBOutlets. 
You have to create property of UIImage to your viewocntroller and using that property load imageView in your GUDdfViewController's viewDidLoad.